# Creating a file text with symfony2 and twig

Tags: php, file, symfony, text, twig

I would like to generate a file text from a symfony2 controller with twig.

Like normal html templating but with plain text, and save the file somewhere.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it.

I wanted to generate bash script.

1. Create the template in the right place such as

   ```
   myBundle/Resources/views/MyController/mytemplate.sh.twig
   ```
2. In a ScriptGenerator class

   ```
   // Load the template
   $template = $this->twig->loadTemplate('myBundle:MyController:mytemplate.sh.twig');
   // Render the whole template
   $script = $template->render($parameters);
   ```
3. Where you want to use it, place this code.

   ```
   namespace myproject\myBundle\Controller;

   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

   use myproject\myBundle\Generator\ScriptGenerator;

   class myController extends Controller
   {
       public function myAction()
       {
           $twig = $this->get('twig');
           $generator = new ScriptGenerator($twig);
           $parameters = array(
               'a parameter' => "whatever"
           );
           $script = $generator->setScript($parameters);

           file_put_contents('whereyouwant',$script);

           ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: For plain text, the Twig file will probably want to make use of the Raw filter, to suppress HTML-escaping. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. You've to put the right format within your route definition (.txt)

You've also to set the right `Content-Type` header,

```
   $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

In fact, The [Response object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony) is commonly populated with HTML code, but it also can contain plain text (with a Content-Type header of text/plain), images or other formats.

You should also put the right format on your template's name,

```
XXXYourBundle:XXXX:temlate_name.txt.twig // In case you're using Twig as a templating Engine
```

Comment: This is nice ! But i would like to generate the file and save it in the user folder. How to do that ? I am trying this method to generate mails (http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Generate-Mails-With-Twig) and the function $template->render but i need to fill multiple blocks before rendering...